# Converting glm::Mat4 to string

Tags: string, glm

Is there any way to simply convert a glm::mat4 to a string and then converting it back to the initial glm::mat4?

Or do i need to create my own converter?

Comment: Why exactly do you need this? 4x4 matrices are not exactly the nicest things to read or display as text

Comment: I have many clients that need to sent their identity matrix to the server(it contain position, rotation, and scaling). And the server send all the matrix to all clients. Im using boost::asio

Comment: For that purpose converting to string would be fundamentally wrong, you have to serialize the data in order to send it, not turn it into a string. On a design level sending the entire matrix to the server seems very wasteful and potentially prone to cheating

Comment: Sending string seems the easiest way with the boost::asio::buffer(). Any other array or vector type gave me a static_cast to Podelements error when receiving data from server. How should i serialize a mat4 to the server?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this, provided by [donaldmunro](https://github.com/donaldmunro):

```
#include <glm/gtx/string_cast.hpp>
..
..
glm::mat4 mat;
..
..
std::cout << glm::to_string(mat) << std::endl;
```

See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/donaldmunro/38841d72c65a1c32f2bf83a4a00a2c9a).

Works well for me!